# Finding Fixed Points

Tags: equation-solving

Starting from an initial point $x_0=1$, I want to compute the fixed point(s) of 
$f(x):=a+b\arctan x$, where (for example) $a=b=1$. I have tried the following commands

$${\rm FixedPoint}[1+1\arctan \# \ \ \&,1],$$

$${\rm NSolve}[x==1+1\arctan x,x],$$

$${\rm Solve}[x==1+1\arctan x,x].$$

But none of these work. Would you please tell me what  is wrong?

Comment: For either `Solve` or `NSolve` you need to include a condition or range, e.g., `Solve[{x == 1 + ArcTan[x], x > 0}, x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FixedPoint[1. + 1. ArcTan[#] &, 1.]
```

Note that Mathematica is case sensitive. Moreover, it is more efficient to start with the machine precision `1.` instead of `1`. Otherwise, exact computations are performed and the algorithm won't terminate.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. It works for these amounts of parameters. But when I set $a=0$ it dose not work any more. What is your idea?

Comment: Oh it works but the fixed point iterations converge rather slowly. You might also want to try `FindRoot[0. + 1. ArcTan[x] == x, {x, 1.}]`, which use Newton's method.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!